Cub Cadet XT1 EFI Engine Doesn't Start Well, Runs Then Eventually Dies Suddenly
I have a 2019 Cub Cadet XT1 riding lawnmower (model: 13A9A1CS056) which has a 9X90HUA MTD engine. It's had a hard time starting and then will suddenly lose power after a bit of mowing.
Starting:
It does start eventually, but only after a few attempts where it will crank but not turn over; I'll wait and then try again and after a number of attempts it kicks over (often with a fair amount of white exhaust smoke).
Running/Power Loss:
It runs fine for a while then dies suddenly with some hard sputters then a quick stop. I am able to restart it but it again usually takes a few tries. I've noticed it doesn't seem as bad when I'm going slower and/or mower blades aren't running. The longer this goes on, the harder it is to get it started and mow. It usually resets for a while once I've come back to it the next day.
What I've tried so far:

Replaced spark plug
Replaced air filter
Oil Change
Ran without air filter for a little bit
Checked mower deck for excessive resistance
Ran it out of gas and replaced with fresh

My Suspicions at this point:

Fuel filter? -- Built into the "non-serviceable" part of the fuel tank (can't find replacement part online anywhere)
Fuel pump? -- Same story as filter
Excessive resistance in crankshaft assembly (out on a limb for this one, not sure how hard that should be to turn by hand?)

To reiterate, this is a fuel injected model, so no carb.
Beyond this, I'm not sure what it would be, or how to verify/fix. Any answers greatly appreciated!

Since it is FI, I'd suggest you (somehow) put a fuel pressure gauge between the fuel pump and the injector(s) to see what the pressure reads and what it reads when.

Sounds like fuel starvation. Have you checked with a flashlight to see if you have floaty bits in the fuel tank? If fuel tank cap was left open in the off-season and remaining fuel evaporated, this could have left a layer of "varnish" in the bottom of the tank which could then become small flakes when fuel is added. Fuel flow through the screen (or the sintered bronze frit) at the outlet could pack these flakes and diminish fuel flow to the point of starvation. The cure for that is to remove tank and drain it, wash with hot water & detergent & lots of shaking; dry thoroughly.

And just to set your mind at ease on the crankshaft friction thing, for a 1 cylinder engine, one time in every two rotations you will feel resistance from compression of air in the cylinder. If you have continuous resistance, it could be drag from the belt that drives the blades. With blades disengaged, there's still a little drag.

Was this stored away for winter with fuel conditioner or emptied out completely? Are you comfortable with disassembling the throttle assembly, looking for deposits from old gas, water, blocking fuel passages? Can you test for spark with plug removed, wired and plug grounded to engine block to observe for spark? Does the spark plug smell of fuel? Can you apply fuel manually into the engine to see if it starts up immediately? This can be either a fuel or spark issue. Compression may be suspect unless you can check compression values.

Thanks all! Great things to try. I think I'll first try to look at the fuel tank with a flashlight as suggested by @MTA . Glad to hear the crankshaft friction is just the compression of air, kinda seems obvious now that I think about it. From there I'll see if I can get a fuel pressure gauge reading like Paulster2 said. I'll report back.

@FDryer, it was stored away for winter with fuel conditioner. I could definitely take a look at the throttle assembly! Doesn't look too hard to get to. I'll report back. I'll also investigate the sparkplug, I recently replaced it and it appeared to have a spark then, but maybe something intermittent may be going on.

Alright update for you all, now that I've had plenty of time to let it do it's thing. I pulled the spark plug (only a few months old) and it was black. Replaced that and it ran like a top for a few weeks. Back to it's old self and sputtering/dying when driving. I pulled the spark plug again and it looked fine this time. What would cause the black plug? And what might still be suspect at this point?
